# How to make @Before of cucumber restricted for only one feature file?

Tags: java, cucumber, web-api-testing

I am using API testing and selenium both in one framework. I added @Before of cucumber to open a browser but for api testing i don't need to open browser. But its opening for both UI and API. How should i restrict so that browser doesn't open up for api? @Before is opening browser for api also which i don't need.

Answer (score 3):

You can use tagged hooks on the Before hook

```
@Before("not @API")
public void before() {
    ....
}
```

Add the tag @API to the feature file with api senarios.

```
@API
Feature: api feature file
```

Comment: `@Before("not @API")` didn't worked for me

But I tagged UI on before hook and it worked
`@Before("@UI")
public void before() {
    ....
}`

Add the tag `@UI` to the feature file with UI senarios
`@UI
Feature: UI feature file`

Thanks @Grasshopper

Comment: @AvinashThakur What version of cucumber are u using?

Comment: cucumber version- 1.2.4  @Grasshopper

Comment: The `not` syntax is for newer versions. The syntax for ur version will be `~@API`. The version 1.2.4 is pretty old, current is 4.5.0.